# Blender animation glitching in Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, unity, .fbx

I have created a gorilla and its animations in Blender, exported the file as an FBX file and then imported it in Unity. The animations works fine in Blender, the loop is perfect for the walking animation. When I play the animations in Unity (in the animation preview and in game) it glitches at the moment where it loops, the arms make a really strange quick move. Is there anything special to do to export Blender animations ?
Tell me if you need more informations.

**EDIT**: Here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb58svuig6ovwhs/Gorilla_Animations.blend?dl=0) to my blender file, if you want to try exporting it and import it in Unity.

Comment: Are you looping the end frame with frame 0 or frame 1?

Comment: Frame 0, is it important ?

Answer (score 1):

The animation in the blend file you uploaded set to end at frame 79, whereas the animation continues to frame 119. I would try double checking the length of the animation as well as the start and end frame when it is exported. When I opened your file and played the animation without doing anything it was 'glitchy' when it looped, but changing the end frame fixed it. Your final animation should start at frame 1 and end at frame 119.

Comment: The end frame is just to visualize the current animation right ? So it wouldn't affect how the file is exported if I am correct. And why should it start at frame 1 ? I already cut the frame 120 to make a smooth loop out of it.

Comment: My mistake then. Staring at frame 0 and ending at 120 should work fine. Usually it is most common to stop one frame before the last pose, and start on the same frame as the first pose so that two frames never have the same pose in a row.

Comment: I would go back and recheck all the animation lengths if you haven't done so already and make sure everything is in order there. I'm not a Unity user so I can't say if it's possible it's an issue with Unity or not, but it sounds possible.